# Network graph visualizer

Tags: networking, graph, data-visualization

I need to get a 2d picture of a network graph. I know the topology. Is there any tool which will help me do so?

Comment: Do you need lib (if yes for what language) or standalone app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: +1 Seems like the perfect tool for the job - I might just use it in some of my projects!

Comment: Can I draw undirected graphs with this tool?

Comment: Yes you can. Instead of using ->, use --. Here is an example: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/process.html ... Click the image to see the source code.

Comment: And here is a directed graph, so you can see the difference in the notation: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/philo.html

Answer (score 2):

There are some open source tools written in Java [here](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-graph-network-visualization-in-java/view).

Answer (score 1):

Yep graphviz is the de facto tool for this. You do not need to look any further. Just use your programming language of choice to spit out a dot file which describes your network. You can drop to programatic definition of graphs using graphviz but that is another issue.

Dot files are nice and simple, anyone could write one.